# How to get my array object into a material ui table

Tags: arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array that I want to get inside a material ui table. This is the structure of my array, which is taken from a file that I import (using react papa parse 3):

https://react-papaparse.js.org/

[image: My array]

This is a link to the code I am trying to get the data into:

https://codesandbox.io/s/htvjz?file=/demo.js

I am a bit confused on the structure of the array, being relatively new at this. Does my row data go one extra level deep with the "data" level in there?

How can I get this into the material ui array table linked to above?

Spent all day on this and going round and round in circles.

Comment: Do you want to create a row from every object in the array and use `data` elements to fill the columns?

Comment: A little unsure what you mean. I want to have the first row (i.e. 0) as the headers and rows 1 to 10 as the data populating the table. In array examples I've seen before, there isn't this extra data level, so I am confused over how to set the rows.

Comment: I have solved the issue. Papaparse had an option to convert the imported csv file into the format you showed above, by adding header:true to the config file. All done!

Answer (score 0):

the link you show uses table. That closely resembles an HTML table.

I can recommend using a  instead. It's easier to read, faster to write, it's more powerful.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

// define which columns you have in your data
const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID' },
  { field: 'firstName', headerName: 'First name' },
  { field: 'lastName', headerName: 'Last name' },
];

// your rows.. you probably won't hard code them but get them from elsewhere
// but they should look like this:
const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon'},
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei'},
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime' },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya' }
];

...

// Then, wherever you want to have your grid, do this:

<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your recommendation. Part of what I am having difficulty with is understanding the structure of my array, so that I can then set the columns and rows like you suggest. There is this extra "data" level and I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: I have solved the issue. Papaparse had an option to convert the imported csv file into the format you showed above, by adding header:true to the config file. All done!